# SearchByKeywordsKbArticleRequest in CRM 4.0 SDK C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4

I am using CRM 4.0 SDK to query kbarticles by keyword entered from a textbox on an asp.net webpage. I am using the `SearchByKeywordsKbArticleRequest` message to do this. Single keywords work fine, but if more than one word is entered a server error occurs. Here is my code:

```cs
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken(); 
token.AuthenticationType = 0;
token.OrganizationName = "omitted";

CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Url = "omitted"
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
//RetrieveMultipleResponse allArticlesResponse = getAllArticles();

SearchByKeywordsKbArticleRequest kb = new SearchByKeywordsKbArticleRequest();
String rawSearchText = keyword;


ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet();
col.Attributes = new string[] { "title", "kbarticleid" };
kb.ColumnSet = col;
kb.SearchText = rawSearchText.Trim();
kb.ReturnDynamicEntities = false;

SearchByKeywordsKbArticleResponse response = 
   (SearchByKeywordsKbArticleResponse)service.Execute(kb);

return response.BusinessEntityCollection;
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

That method uses the SQL Full-Text indexing service, so you would need to have full-text indexing setup in your database. You should be able to get more information about what's going wrong by enabling tracing in CRM. See:

http://social.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/crmdevelopment/thread/6A4CE7A3-29F3-4E5A-9A89-8E35D6FD05B9